# Sencha touch 2.0 : Custom model validation with stores

Tags: validation, sencha-touch-2

I've been reading and trying to use the method proposed in this thread:
[How to add a custom validation rule to a model in Sencha Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414115/how-to-add-a-custom-validation-rule-to-a-model-in-sencha-touch/9276996#9276996).

So first, I add a custom validation type to the Ext.data.validations singleton:

```
if (Ext.data) {
    Ext.data.validations.custom = function (config, value) {
        if (config && Ext.isFunction(config.fn)) {
            //this should be the model
            if (config.self) {
                return config.fn.call(config.self, value);
            } else {
                return config.fn(value);
            } 
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
    Ext.data.validations.customMessage = "Error";
}
```

Then, since I am using ST2, I apply what Ben G proposes. I extend Ext.data.Model to include a reference to 'self' (this).

Ext.define('MyApp.model.CustomModelBase', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

```
    //adding an initializer to let custom validators access "self"
    init : function () {
        var i, len;
        if (this.config.validations) {
            for (i = 0, len = this.config.validations.length; i < len; i++) {
                this.config.validations[i].self = this;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, I create a model extending the CustomModelBase. Let's call this model MyApp.model.MyModel. I define a custom validation rule inside it.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'MyApp.model.CustomModelBase',
    config: {
        fields: [ {name:'field1'} ],

        validations: [
            { 
                type: 'custom', field: 'field1', message: "Your field is bad",
                fn: function (value) {
                     **console.log(this);**
                   return (value>0);
                }
            }           
        ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id  : 'MyApp-Local-Storage'
       }        
    }
});
```

Now, everything works well when only one instance of MyModel is created.

The problem is when I have store of MyModel's. When you do that, the reference to 'this' received in the fn function seems to always be the latest item in the store.
More precisely, the **console.log(this)** always outputs the latest Record object of the store .

How can I fix this ?

update:
I wonder if it's not because all the store records share the same model instance ?
Can we do something about it or does the whole method described above fail for using stores ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution (in the Sencha Touch 1.0 forum, but it worked for me in ST2):
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122680-Conditional-fields-validations

It requires an override of the validate() method of the Model class, but if you don't mind then this is easier than what I exposed earlier...