# Does exists a Validation framework in ExtJs 3.4?

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs4, extjs3, extjs-mvc

I'm developing with extjs 3.4 and I'd like to know if exists a pluging or library that I can used to validate models

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242)

Comment: Sorry Matt, I've been googling and I've seen nothing related. I know that, there'll be more people interested in knowing the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the above **no built-in framework for modal validation**

Try for writing custom validation
[ExtJS Model Validations: Dates (How to)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376506/extjs-model-validations-dates-how-to)

and check this also
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?125545-EXTJS-4.0-Model-and-remote-validation

Comment: Hi Ren, thank your answer. I guessed that extjs 4 had got something like that.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no built-in framework for validation. In ExtJs 4.0 there are some pieces - like validation in model, validation in forms but they are not related and disconnected.

If you need something more complete than that - you need to write it.